# Inspect failed HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, html, http

Is there a way to inspect failed HTTP requests in javascript? For example

```
<img src="foo.com">
```

will fail with a message (in Chrome dev tool):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
```

I would like to capture the same HTTP failure in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to log the error as soon there is one. Here as soon the `timeout` is reached, it will throw you an error event.

```js
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}, true);
```

```html
<img src="foo.com">
```

Output:

```
{
  "isTrusted": true,
  "NONE": 0,
  "CAPTURING_PHASE": 1,
  "AT_TARGET": 2,
  "BUBBLING_PHASE": 3,
  "type": "error",
  "target": <img src="foo.com"></img>,
  "currentTarget": {
    /**id:2**/
    "postMessage": function () { [native code] },
...
```

Comment: :: Hi @Clint if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.